# Cannot Index on array of int RavenDB

Tags: c#, indexing, ravendb

I'm trying to query on a property of type IEnumerable int to find all documents in the collection that contain an integer value in this property.

I've tried to accomplish this with an index on the property to return a list of id's which satisfy the query. I am projecting the id's in the query however I'm getting a list of id 0's.

**Index**

```
public class Merchants_CategoryId : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Merchant>
{
    public class Result
    {
        public int MerchantId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<int> CategoryIds { get; set; }
    }

    public Merchants_CategoryId()
    {
        Map = merchants => merchants.Select(merchant => new
        {
            CategoryIds = merchant.Header.CategoryIds,
            MerchantId = merchant.Header.Id
        });
    }
}
```

**Query**

```
return await session
                .Query<Merchants_CategoryId.Result, Merchants_CategoryId>()
                .Where(x => x.CategoryIds.Any(c => c == categoryId))
                .Select(x => x.MerchantId)
                .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Index:

```
public class Merchants_CategoryId : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Merchant>
{
      public class Result
      {
          public int MerchantId { get; set; }
          public int CategoryId { get; set; }
      }


      Map = merchants => from merchant in merchants
                         from categoryId in merchant.Header.CategoryIds
                         select new
                         {
                             MerchantId = merchant.Header.Id,
                             CategoryId = categoryId 
                         };

      Index(x => x.CategoryId, FieldIndexing.Yes);
      Store(x => x.MerchantId, FieldStorage.Yes);
}
```

Query:

```
return await session
            .Query<Merchants_CategoryId.Result, Merchants_CategoryId>()
            .Where(x => x.CategoryId == categoryId)
            .Select(x => x.MerchantId)
            .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: This is still returning a list of 0 merchant id's.